# Making an Agda program output to the console

Tags: io, program-entry-point, agda

I've been using Agda for 9 months now. For the first time, I find myself wanting to "run" (as a top-level executable) an Agda program that prints a string. Call me old-fashioned.

I can write a program that *computes* a string and get Agda to show me the *value* of the string in interactive mode (or Emacs). But the string is long and has embedded newlines. I would like it actually printed out.

By way of comparison, in GHCi I can do something like this:

```
Prelude> putStrLn "hello, world!"
hello, world!
```

But in Agda's interactive mode I get this:

```
Main> putStrLn "hello, world!"
.IO.♯-15
('h' .Data.Colist.Colist.∷
 .Data.Colist.♯-2 'h'
 ('e' .Data.List.List.∷
  'l' .Data.List.List.∷
  'l' .Data.List.List.∷
  'o' .Data.List.List.∷
  ',' .Data.List.List.∷
  ' ' .Data.List.List.∷
  'w' .Data.List.List.∷
  'o' .Data.List.List.∷
  'r' .Data.List.List.∷
  'l' .Data.List.List.∷
  'd' .Data.List.List.∷ '!' .Data.List.List.∷ .Data.List.List.[]))
>>
.IO.♯-16
('h' .Data.Colist.Colist.∷
 .Data.Colist.♯-2 'h'
 ('e' .Data.List.List.∷
  'l' .Data.List.List.∷
  'l' .Data.List.List.∷
  'o' .Data.List.List.∷
  ',' .Data.List.List.∷
  ' ' .Data.List.List.∷
  'w' .Data.List.List.∷
  'o' .Data.List.List.∷
  'r' .Data.List.List.∷
  'l' .Data.List.List.∷
  'd' .Data.List.List.∷ '!' .Data.List.List.∷ .Data.List.List.[]))
```

So, how do I take a program like the following and run it so that I observe the effects that have accumulated in the `IO` value?

```
module Temp where

   open import Data.Unit
   open import IO

   main : IO ⊤
   main = putStrLn "Hello, world!"
```

I notice there's a Haskell-style `run` function declared in Agda's `IO` module, but I haven't found a way to make that help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Agda IO systems has basically two layers: the lower layer (`IO.Primitive`) is just a proxy to the Haskell `IO`, the higher layer (`IO`) is a wrapper built on top.

The problem with IO is that it doesn't play very nicely with termination checker. So instead of having to define every funcion with `{-# NON_TERMINATING #-}`, you create a new (coinductive) data type that describes IO actions and focus all problems with nontermination into one single function - `run`.

The `run` function then just translates the desription of IO action given by the high-level `IO` type into an actual IO action (`IO.Primitive`) that can be run by the runtime system.

Here's how your "Hello, world!" program should look like:

```
open import IO

main = run (putStrLn "Hello, world!")
```

Comment: If you then want to compile your program, make sure you have `agda-lib-ffi` installed (run `cabal install` in `ffi` directory of Agda stdlib). You can then use Emacs command `C-c C-x C-c` to actually compile the module you're working with.

Comment: Great, thanks. (All those tips were essential :) I also needed to upgrade to v0.8.1 of the standard library, to avoid [this problem](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/commit/294d9d533a810957a9b0e7ff3d15e7269abb86da).

Comment: Btw, what's the deal with the `MAlonzo` directory that now appears in my project?

Comment: Well, the compiler works by creating Haskell source code (`.hs`) and then running GHC on it. The `MAlonzo` directory is where this code is stored (also inferface files, object files, etc).

Comment: Right. So the only way to observe the effects of an Agda program is by compiling to a binary and then running the binary - there is no "interactive" (REPL-based) equivalent, as one gets with GHCi.

Comment: I don't think there is. While agda executable does have `--interactive` mode, it doesn't run IO (and it's not very supported, but that's another thing).